# Issue in ascending order code

Tags: assembly, x86

What is the issue(s) in my code? If you look at code in below, I'm trying to have ascending sort with easy way, But it cant run.

We have an array using in the code.Its a pre-defined array include a few members on each cell of array.So We're trying to sort `arr1`.

```
datasg segment para 'data'
  arr1 db 8,2,7,4,3
datasg ends

codesg segment para 'code'   

main proc far
  Assume cs:codesg, ds:datasg
    mov ax, datasg
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, OFFSET arr1
    mov cx, 5
    mov dx, cx
    L1:      
       mov si, 0
       mov ax, si
       inc ax
       mov di, ax
       mov dx, cx
    L2:
       mov al, [bx][si]
       cmp al, [bx][di]
       jg L4
    L3:
       inc si
       inc di
       dec dx
       cmp dx, 00
       je L1
       jg L2
    L4:
       mov al, [bx][si]
       mov ah, [bx][di]
       mov [bx][si], ah
       mov [bx][di], al
       inc si
       inc di       
       dec dx
       cmp dx, 00
       je L1
       jg L2
    Exit:
       mov ax, 4c00h
       int 21h
main endp
codesg ends
End main
```

The environment I'm using is, emu8086.

**Edit 1:**

It's seems to be it is just frequent jumping between `L1` , `L2` , `L3` , Kinda an indefinitely loop. In fact, there is no error upon running. If the code hasn't problems,
How do i can for print sorted array (at final) to user as export?

Comment: why can't it run? what is the problem upon running?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, I've edited the post,Read it again,please.

Comment: you can see how to print here: http://911programming.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/emu8086-read-a-string-from-keyboard/ i don't think emu8086 has printf, so you will probably need to do your own conversion to ascii

Comment: Best bet: step through the program, *one* instruction at a time, and examine what is happening (registers, memory) at each step.  You'll find the problem this way, I assure you.